# Populating multiple choice field and changing it with onChange in React

Tags: reactjs, field, dropdown, onchange, multiple-choice

I have a multiple choice dropdown menu that populates with data that is stored in my database. When I try adding or deleting one of the options in the dropdown menu, the change is not reflected in the field. My code is below:

```
            <div className={styles.below}>
              Items:
              {items.map(item =>
                <Field
                  key={item}
                  name="items"
                  component={AutoComplete}
                  required={true}
                  options={item}
                  /* placeholder={initialData.tas} */
                  value={values.items}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
              )}
            </div>
```

I want the changes I make to be reflected in the dropdown menu field. Currently, if I click to add an option that wasn't selected, or if I click to un-add an option that was already selected, nothing happens. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Could you please paste your full component?